# Table of corresponding grammatical terms in English and German?

Tags: discussion

What about starting a community wiki with a list of grammatical terms in English and German? Often, I'm facing the problem to call a certain grammatical phenomenon by its German name, but I'm unsure about its counterpart in English. So I think it would be useful to have such a table of terms, either sorted alphabetically or systematically.

Comment: So let's say you have the list, "dependent clause — Nebensatz, gender — Genus, litotes — Litotes, metathesis — Metathese, syllepsis — Syllepse", and so on and so forth, and it's two thousand terms long or something. Now, how do you look up "metathesis" in that huge list *if you don't know that you're looking for metathesis*? (And if you do know that you're looking for metathesis, why not just use a dictionary or Wikipedia?)

Comment: hmm - to be honest, i didn't consider the fact that the list may grow extensivly. Dictionaries may not cover such special terms, and they may offer divergent translations. WP may be helpful in many cases, but for example, the german „Akkusativobjekt“ is linked to the english "Accusative case", what isn't the same precisely. So i thought about some sort of "technical dictionary", with hyperlinks to external pages explaining the grammatical term. But maybe a community wiki may not be the approrpiate "medium" for such a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

My favorite German-English online dictionary http://dict.leo.org knows `Akkusativobjekt`. Linguistic terms are marked in a special way (`[ling.]`).

Since it also has community feedback features, it might make sense to add translations there instead of compiling a separate list here.

(Disclaimer: I'm in no way affiliated with dict.leo.org, I just happen to use it a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

Beside dict.leo.org, as suggested by Heinzi, a well organized collection of synonyms in the tag database could be helpful.